# Tem como usar componentes nativos na programação web?

Tags: javascript, html, react

Gostaria de saber se eu consigo chamar o dropdown picker nativo de um celular ios ou android, usando código javascript na web? ou uma biblioteca react.

por exemplo essa [lib](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-picker-select) do react-native:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Se utilizar um `<select>` automaticamente irá utilizar não?

Answer (score 1):

Não tem como. Componentes nativos são diferentes dos renderizados pela web. No React-Native isso só é possível por causa da **bridge** que chama os componentes nativos de cada plataforma.

Pra web você teria que estilizar cada um separado ou criar um estilo para os dois.